# Tom-Select (or Selectize.js) Remote data for Option Groups

Tags: selectize.js, tom-select

I am trying to use remote data for tom-select (https://tom-select.js.org/examples/optgroups/).  I am at a loss how to configure option groups with remote data. I have the select loading with remote data like this:

```
"optgroup": "1 Materials | 1.2 Gravel",
"value": 65,
"label": "1.2.1 Tanks"
```

From the docs I got the impression that you set `optgroupField: 'optgroup'` and the option groups would be set automatically. Do I need to add the optgroups array to my JSON data? I can't seem to find any examples of remote data with option groups anywhere.

tom-select shares much of it's code from Selectize.js so I am cross tagging this also.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in the selectize world:

https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/issues/151#issuecomment-111056161

I added a group id:

```
"optgroup_id": 13,
"optgroup": "1 Materials | 1.1 Pipe, valves & fittings",
"value": 5,
"label": "1.1.1 Line Pipe"
```

Reset the group field: `optgroupField: 'optgroup_id'` then added this after the json callback in `load`:

```
json.items.forEach((item) => {
this.addOptionGroup(item['optgroup_id'], { label: item['optgroup'] } );
  });
this.refreshItems()
```

I am also playing around with adding a second `optgroups` json array with just the groups to avoid cycling through all the options.

I hope there is a better answer - will leave this open for that.  Hoping this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

With TomSelect you can format remote data into option groups like this:

```js
new TomSelect('#id', {
  // these are the defaults
  optgroupField: 'optgroup',
  optgroupValueField: 'value',
  optgroupLabelField: 'label',
  // specify your option groups
  optgroups: [
    {value: 'foo', label: 'Foo Group'},
    {value: 'bar', label: 'Bar Group'},
  ],
});
```

Your data should then include an `optgroup` property for each item.

```js
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Result",
    optgroup: "foo",
  }
]
```